# Nginx - Multiple Websites One Sever

Tags: nginx, linode

Having a bit of a problem getting multiple sites on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS / NGINX.

I have a site setup that's working great. Now that I want to add new sites, which I need to test before going live, I can't access any other site except the first site I added. This is basically what I want to do:

x.x.x.x (/) server root (My Server IP): "Welcome to Nginx" page which eventually I'll turn into some informational page

-> (/domain1) https:// domain1 dot com (Secured by SSL Let's Encrypt) - this domain is currently working nicely, but when I go to x.x.x.x it redirects to https:// domain1 dot com right away so I can't get to http:// x.x.x.x and see the welcome to nginx page.

-> (/domain2) https:// domain2 dot com (Secured by SSL Let's Encrypt)

-> (/other domains) etc

which in the testing and setup phase, I'd like to access via http:// x.x.x.x/domain2 dot com then just point the nameservers do the SSL which hopefully can be one cert per domain and not serve the wrong certs to the wrong domain. The sites will be a mix of Wordpress and normal static HTML sites.

Is any of this possible?

### Here's my setup:

Linode VPS (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

NGINX config (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf):

```
   user www-data;
   worker_processes auto;
   pid /run/nginx.pid;

   events {
   worker_connections 768;
   # multi_accept on;
   }

   http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # uncommented this 8/5/2017
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype imag$

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
```

/var/www/directory

```
  jupiter@hydrogen:/var/www$ ls -la
  total 24
  drwxr-xr-x  6 root    root    4096 Aug  5 19:10 .
  drwxr-xr-x 12 root    root    4096 Jul 17 12:12 ..
  drwxr-xr-x  2 jupiter jupiter 4096 Aug  5 19:38 html
  drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 Jul 17 13:01 letsencrypt
  drwxr-xr-x  2 jupiter jupiter 4096 Aug  5 19:12 domain2 dot com
  drwxr-xr-x  7 root    root    4096 Jul 28 11:00 domain1 dot com
  jupiter@hydrogen:/var/www$
```

content of (/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain1.conf)

```
## Serves https://domain1 dot com
## Removed default_server from the listen directives 08/5/2017
server {
    server_name domain1 dot com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1 dot com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1 dot com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1 dot com/fullchain.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;

    #browser caching of static assets
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 7d;
    }

    #browser caching of css and js
    location ~*  \.(css|js)$ {
            expires 3d;
    }

    root /var/www/domain1.com;
    index index.html;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php =404;
    }
}

## https://domain1 dot com redirects to https://www.domain1 dot com
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain1.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1 dot com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1 dot com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1 dot com/fullchain.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;

    location / {
            return 301 https://www.domain1 dot com$request_uri;
    }
}

## Removed default_server from the listen directives 08/5/2017
#server {
#        listen 80;
#        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
#        server_name domain1 dot com www.domain1 dot com;
#
#        include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
#
#        location / {
#                return 301 https://www.domain1 dot com$request_uri;
#        }
#}
```

contents of (/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain2.conf)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name domain2 dot com www.domain2 dot com;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    root /var/www/domain2 dot com;
    index index.html;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

/var/www/domain2 and /var/www/html both have index.html files in them. I would really appreciate anyone's help in this.

Comment: In your example `x.x.x.x` **is** the domain name. `nginx` will choose one `server` block to process the request. In the absence of a `server_name x.x.x.x;` statement in one of your `server` blocks, the default server will be used. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for more.

Comment: @RichardSmith

Thanks for your reply, however, this is my default.conf

    `server {
         listen 80 default_server;
         listen [::]:80 default_server;
         root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name x.x.x.x;
}`